# How to add 'open folder as root' in Elementary OS file manager context menu?

Tags: files, file-manager, menu, elementary-os

[Here](http://elementaryos.org/answers/how-to-add-a-option-likeopen-terminal-here-into-the-right-click-menu) it is the solution in order to add the 'open terminal here' into the context menu of Elementary OS' file manager (generically called 'Files' - the executable is `pantheon-files`).

For that specific demand, the idea is to create the file `/usr/share/contractor/terminal.contract` and add something like

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Open Terminal here
Icon=terminal
Description=Open Terminal here
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=pantheon-terminal -d %U
Gettext-Domain=pantheon-terminal
```

But how to adapt that and have a model to add other commands, namely - following my order of priorities - 'open folder as root'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to create 'Open folder as root' context menu command - **and in order to create any new such command** - a **new** `*.contract` file has to be created in `/usr/share/contractor`.

To create the file in `gedit`:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/contractor/Open_as_admin.contract`

For 'Open folder as root' - that file would have to contain something like

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Open folder as root
Icon=gksu-root-terminal
Description=Open folder as root
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=gksudo pantheon-files -d %U
Gettext-Domain=pantheon-files
```

(but no icon appears in te context menu anyway)

[image]

Comment: @ciprius Great explanation! Do you know if is possible a submenu? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @costales - do not know, sorry

Comment: If its not showing up for you make sure you have gksudo installed. I didn't and I had to remove parts of the config file until I realized what was stopping it from showing up.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Open folder as root
Icon=gksu-root-terminal
Description=Open folder as root
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=/usr/bin/io.elementary.files-pkexec
Gettext-Domain=pantheon-files
```

This worked for me in Elementary OS 5 Juno 01/20/2019.
Also, use nano instead of gedit.

Comment: (1) This is the same as the accepted answer except for one line. What is the significance of that line? Is your answer better than the other one? (2) What’s wrong with gedit?

Comment: Brief: gksu is deprecated. It is removed from Debian, Ubuntu 18.04 and other newer Linux distribution version.

Comment: nano is already in the system gedit is not you would need to install it.

Comment: @G-Man - not using elementary now but I welcome this answer, as that line seems better. (Maybe a comment would have been preferable, but this is ok for a new user). I would even integrate that to my answer.  I prefer gedit on all gtk desktops though, I simply never use nano.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated on 29 Jan 2020

**OS: `elementary OS 5.1 Hera`**

The accepted answer is correct but **needs more refinement**

1. `sudo sed -i '/pkexec/ s/$/ $@/' /usr/bin/io.elementary.files-pkexec`

   Make `io.elementary.files-pkexec` accept initial directories
2. Create the contractor

```bsh
sudo tee /usr/share/contractor/open-as-root.contract <<EOF
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Open elevated Files here
Icon=gksu-root-terminal
Description=Open folder as root
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=io.elementary.files-pkexec %U
Gettext-Domain=io.elementary.files
EOF
```

Create the contractor at **`/usr/share/contractor/open-as-root.contract`**

[image: Context menu]

[image: Elevated window]