# How to add custom script in Elementary OS file manager context menu?

Tags: files, elementary-os, file-manager, pantheon

do you know if there is possibility to add custom script as element in context menu? I've seen similar threads related adding "[open folder as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92494/how-to-add-open-folder-as-root-in-elementary-os-file-manager-context-menu/92508#92508)" and "[make executable/run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192158/how-to-add-make-executable-and-run-entries-to-elementary-os-file-manager-con)" entries, but still I'm not able to make such element in context menu work with my script.
My script works perfectly when I'm calling it by name from terminal (it is in `/bin/`):
`myscript.sh filename`.
Do you how the syntax of Exec in New Contractor Entery shoud looks like to makes it work?

Answer (score -1):

```
Exec=myscript.sh "%U"
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).